# What does the '-c' option do in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

What does the `-c` flag do in `gcc`?

For example, what's the difference between

```
gcc -c output0.c
```

and

```
gcc output0.c
```

?

I know the second one makes a `.a` file, but I don't know what a `.a` file is.

Also, what does `-o` do in

```
gcc output0.o -o output0
```

Is it just to name the output file right?

Comment: I recommend you read the [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). For example, the section named ["3.2 Options Controlling the Kind of Output"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

Comment: I think the best you can do is read the manual page for gcc.

Comment: "Compile only" `gcc -c` produces only object file. To produce an executable, you have to call linker again. May be, `man gcc`? :)

Comment: Generally, looking at the other questions that you already asked, you need to learn how to use freely available information before bothering others with your questions. If you are on a linux system, `man` is your friend. And if you don't find it locally, use a search engine, first.

Answer (score 20):

> **-c**
>
> Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link. The linking
> stage simply is not done. The ultimate output is in the form of an
> object file for each source file.
>
> By default, the object file name for a source file is made by
> replacing the suffix .c, .i, .s, etc., with .o. Unrecognized input
> files, not requiring compilation or assembly, are ignored.

> **-o file**
>
> Place output in file file. This applies regardless to whatever sort of
> output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object
> file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code. If -o is not
> specified, the default is to put an executable file in a.out, the
> object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler file in
> source.s, a precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch, and all
> preprocessed C source on standard output.

More can be found in [GCC Manual Page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

Answer (score 5):

From [`man gcc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) (section *"Options Controlling the Kind of Output"*):

> ...
>
> [-c](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c)  Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form
> of an object file for each source file.
>
> By default, the object file name for a source file is made by
> replacing the suffix .c, .i, .s, etc., with .o.
>
> Unrecognized input files, not requiring compilation or assembly, are
> ignored.
>
> ...

Answer (score 3):

[-c](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c) will instruct GCC to only compile the source file to an .o (object) file, but it does not invoke the linker.

With a project containing many .c files, one will typically compile first all .c files to .o files and then link everything together with the libraries.

> **-c**
>
> Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an object
> file for each source file.
>
> By default, the object file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix >.c, .i, .s, etc., with .o.
>
> Unrecognized input files, not requiring compilation or assembly, are ignored.

[Source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)