# compile multiple source file in c

Tags: c, makefile

I have written c program, Which has 3 file(.c ) , Main program has
two threads and one file has mysql connection function, One file has
thread functions definition. I don't know how to compile all these
codes, Normally I tried like this,

```
cc -pthread main.c
```

But if I compile like this I am getting error called mysql functions
are undefined But I have written thread as separate program and
mysql as separate program and complied individually , it complied
successfully and I got output. So please help me to compile my
project  File names are,

`main.c` (2 threads are declared) `functions.c` (thread function
definition, and mysql func declared) `db.c` ( mysql function
definition)

please help to compile my code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard (read as **impossible**) to tell ___exactly___ what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If you are trying to combine three separate programs which each compile and (you imply) run individually, you should restructure your code and use `.h` header file(s) to share their definitions. It's unlikely that module files that form a part of the whole will compile and run separately.

Comment: Additionally, please acclimate yourself to not only providing the significant details, but to not adding noise with useless details. For example, it is fully unimportant that your program has 2 threads or that one uses mysql, etc. You'll find that when you think about your problem enough to create a concise proper question, you will understand your own situation better.

Answer (score 2):

You have two basic options when compiling multiple .c files:

Option 1)

`cc file1.c file2.c file3.c -o executable_name`

Advantage: simple

Disadvantage: if all you change is one file you are recompiling all the files

Option 2)

```
 cc file1.c -c -o file1.o
 cc file2.c -c -o file2.o
 cc file3.c -c -o file3.o
 cc file1.o file2.o file3.o -o executable_name
```

Advantage: If you change one file you do not have to recompile everything

Disadvantage: Multiple commands (but you should use a Makefile at this point)

The `-c` flag tells the compiler to [compiler but not link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724315/what-does-c-paramater-do-in-gcc).  You don't want to link as you have not compiled all of your files.  The final invocation of `cc` links all the `.o` files into the executable `executable_name`

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit difficult to understand exactly what you need, but I can tell you from what you've stated that you'll need to include specific libraries in your compile statement you currently are not. Also, a -l flag needs to prefix your libraries.

Try something like this:

```
gcc -lpthread main.c functions.c db.c -o main $(mysql_config --libs)
```

To explain, `mysql_config --libs` returns all the configuration libraries needed to run mysql ddl inside your C program.

Given your updates on your file declarations I'm guessing you're a Java programmer. C is not Java. If you are declaring functions you are only going to use once in `main.c` you should put them inside `main.c` unless you need them to be portable.

Comment: He has two additional source files... `functions.c` and `db.c`. While he could simply add those to the singular command you've given him and it would probably link, that's not a helpful suggestion in the long run.

Comment: He edited to add the two extra source files after I posted my answer. Updating now

Comment: Thanks for your help, But i had tried above compile method . If there is any way by using make file????