# What's the meaning of gcc '-c' and gcc '-o'?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, putty

When I created makefile, I wrote

```
test: main.o 1.o
  gcc -o test main.o 1.o

main.o: main.c a.h
  gcc -c main.c

1.o: 1.c a.h
  gcc -c 1.c
```

but I don't get why I use -o in the first line and -c in the second, third line.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does -c option do in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14724315/608639)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those options do very different things:

- [-c](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c) tells GCC to compile a source file into a `.o` object file.  Without that option, it'll default to compiling *and linking* the code into a complete executable program, which only works if you give it all your `.c` files at the same time.  To compile files individually so they can be linked later, you need `-c`.
- [-o](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o) sets the name of the output file that GCC produces.  You're using it when linking object files to make a complete program, and the default output filename for that is `a.out`.  If you don't want your program to be called `a.out`, you use `-o` to specify a different name.